# A different object with same identifier was already associated with the session error

Tags: c#, nhibernate, join, castle-activerecord, linq-to-nhibernate

**Scenario:** I have a customer object with lazy loading enabled. I use that throughout the program to call a list of customer for a listbox. It has relationships to the Division_Customer_Rel, Division_Email_Rel and Email_Address objects. All off the relationships have `Lazy = true, Cascade = ManyRelationCascadeEnum.AllDeleteOrphan, Inverse = true`.

**Problem:** When I am using a new session and I try and save it gives me the error `A different object with same identifier was already associated with the session`. I have tried to use LINQ to return the list without using a new session by joining the other objects in the call but I'm not sure how to use ActiveRecordLinq<> when joining.

```
private Customer GetCustomer()
    {
       return (from x in ActiveRecordLinq.AsQueryable<Customer>()
         where x.Customer_ID == ((Customer)lst_customers.SelectedItem).Customer_ID 
         select x).First();
    }
```

Code that produces the error

```
using (new SessionScope())
                {
                //var sess = GetSession();
                //var customer =
                //    sess.CreateCriteria<Customer>("c").CreateCriteria("c.DivisionCustomer_Rels").List<Customer>().
                //        First();
                var customer = GetCustomer();
                    /* Ensure user wishes to commit the data. */

                    var result =
                        MessageBox.Show(
                            @"You are about to submit changes to customer: " + customer.CustomerName + @"." +
                            Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine +
                            @"Submit Changes?", @"Submit Customer Changes", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                            MessageBoxIcon.Question);
                    if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
                    {
                        customer.CustomerName = txt_custName.Text;
                        customer.NamcisNumber = Convert.ToInt32(txt_namcis.Text);
                        customer.DCA = chk_dca.Checked;
                        customer.CustomerType = (CustomerType_Code) cmb_custType.SelectedItem;
                        customer.AOR = (AOR_Code) cmbAOR.SelectedItem;
                        customer.CSRep = (CSRep_Code) cmbCSRep.SelectedItem;
                        customer.DivisionCustomer_Rels.Clear(); 
                        foreach (var t in lst_SectorCust.Items)
                        {
                            customer.DivisionCustomer_Rels.Add(new Division_Customer_Rel
                                                                   {
                                                                       Customer = customer
                                                                       ,
                                                                       Division = (Division_Code) t,
                                                                       MarkedForDeletion = false
                                                                   });
                        }
                        customer.CircuitCustomer_Rels.Clear();
                        foreach (var t in lst_Circuit.Items)
                        {
                            customer.CircuitCustomer_Rels.Add(new Circuit_Customer_Rel
                                                                  {
                                                                      Circuit = (Circuit) t,
                                                                      Customer = customer,
                                                                      MarkedForDeletion = false
                                                                  });
                        }
                        customer.EmailAddresses.Clear();
                        foreach (var t in lst_email.Items)
                        {
                            var temp = (Email_Address)t;
                            temp.Customer = customer;
                            customer.EmailAddresses.Add(temp);

                        }
                        ////Need to manage the emails this way otherwise we recieve an error because of lazy loading
                        //foreach (var temp in lst_email.Items.Cast<Email_Address>())
                        //{
                        //    temp.Customer = customer;
                        //    if (!customer.EmailAddresses.Any(s=>temp.ToString().Equals(s.ToString())) && !customer.EmailAddresses.Contains(temp))
                        //    {
                        //        customer.EmailAddresses.Add(temp);
                        //    }

                        //}

                        //var text = IList<Email_Address> lst_email.Items;
                        //var tem = customer.EmailAddresses.Except(lst_email.Items);
                        //for (var i = customer.EmailAddresses.Count - 1; i >= 0;i-- )
                        //{
                        //    var temp = customer.EmailAddresses[i];

                        //    for (var j = 0; j < lst_email.Items.Count; j++)
                        //    {
                        //        if (temp.ToString()!=lst_email.Items[j].ToString())
                        //        {
                        //            customer.EmailAddresses.Remove(temp);
                        //        }
                        //    }
                        //}
                        customer.DivisionEmail_Rels.Clear(); 
                        customer.Save();
                        MessageBox.Show(@"Changes submitted.");
                    }
                    //SessionScope.Current
                }
```

Email Address Class

```
   namespace Sens
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using Castle.ActiveRecord;

    [Serializable, ActiveRecord("dbo.Email_Address")]
    public class Email_Address : ActiveRecordValidationBase<Email_Address>
    {
        #region Constructors

        public Email_Address()
        {
            DivisionEmail_Rels = new List<Division_Email_Rel>();
        }

        #endregion

        #region Properties

        [PrimaryKey(Column = "Email_ID")]
// ReSharper disable InconsistentNaming
        public int Email_ID { get; private set; }

        [BelongsTo(Column = "Customer_ID")]
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }

        [Property(Column = "[Email]", NotNull = true, Length = 100)]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [BelongsTo(Column = "EmailType_ID")]
        public EmailType_Code EmailType { get; set; }

        [Property(Column = "[ReceivesSENS]", NotNull = true)]
        public bool ReceivesSENS { get; set; }

        [Property(Column = "[MarkedForDeletion]", NotNull = true)]
        public bool MarkedForDeletion { get; set; }

        #endregion

        #region HasMany DivisionEmail_Rels

        [HasMany(typeof(Division_Email_Rel), Lazy = false,Cascade=ManyRelationCascadeEnum.AllDeleteOrphan,Inverse=true)]
        public IList<Division_Email_Rel> DivisionEmail_Rels { get; set; }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Division Customer Rel

```
    namespace Sens
{
    using System;
    using Castle.ActiveRecord;

    [Serializable, ActiveRecord("dbo.Division_Customer_Rel")]
    public class Division_Customer_Rel : ActiveRecordValidationBase<Division_Customer_Rel>
    {
        #region Constructors

        #endregion

        #region Properties

        [PrimaryKey(Column = "Relationship_ID")]
// ReSharper disable InconsistentNaming
        public int Relationship_ID { get; private set; }
// ReSharper restore InconsistentNaming

        [BelongsTo(Column = "Customer_ID")]
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }

        [BelongsTo(Column = "Division_ID")]
        public Division_Code Division { get; set; }

        [Property(Column = "[MarkedForDeletion]", NotNull = true)]
        public bool MarkedForDeletion { get; set; }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Division Email Rel

```
 #region namespace imports

using System;
using Castle.ActiveRecord;

#endregion

namespace Sens
{
    [Serializable, ActiveRecord("dbo.Division_Email_Rel")]
    public class Division_Email_Rel : ActiveRecordValidationBase<Division_Email_Rel>
    {
        #region Constructors

        #endregion

        #region Properties

        [PrimaryKey(Column = "Relationship_ID")]
// ReSharper disable InconsistentNaming
            public int Relationship_ID { get; private set; }

// ReSharper restore InconsistentNaming

        [BelongsTo(Column = "Email_ID", Cascade = CascadeEnum.All)]
        public Email_Address Email { get; set; }

        [BelongsTo(Column = "Division_ID")]
        public Division_Code Division { get; set; }

        [BelongsTo(Column = "Customer_ID")]
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }

        [Property(Column = "[MarkedForDeletion]", NotNull = true)]
        public bool MarkedForDeletion { get; set; }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. What does LINQ to SQL have to do here? It's an entirely different library. 2. Can you post the code that throws "A different object with same identifier was already associated with the session"?

Comment: can you also post the code for the Division_Customer_Rel, Division_Email_Rel and Email_Address classes?

Comment: @Mauricio Scheffer I will post the code on Monday (Work related)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I finally got it to save after googling everywhere for an answer was to clear the Email_Addresses instead of clearing them.

```
SessionScope.Current.Evict(customer.EmailAddresses);
                        foreach (var t in lst_email.Items)
                        {
                            var temp = (Email_Address)t;
                            temp.Customer = customer;
                            customer.EmailAddresses.Add(temp);

                        }
```

Not sure why this worked though, if someone could explain that would be great. I posting this on here so that hopefully it will save some time for the next person encountering this error .

Answer (score 1):

The evict removes that specific "Email_Address" reference from the NHibernate first level cache.

From customer.EmailAddresses you have removed all the email address in NHibernate first level cache.

You are then obtaining items from list of emails in lst_email and adding them into the EmailAddress for the customer as new objects.